# Node-Mysql Transaction rollback not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, transactions, node-mysql

js as well as mysql. I'm in trouble with transactions.

In the function below i did exactly as they said here https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions. But its not working :|

```
function insertMemoTransaction(){
  pool.getConnection(function(error, connection){
    if(error){
      alert("Somthing is wrong with your connection");
    }
    connection.beginTransaction(function(error){
      if(error) { throw error; }
      var idfield = scope.find('input[name="Party_Id"]');
      var Party_Id;
      if(idfield.val() == '-1'){
        var newParty = {
          // An object
        };
        connection.query("INSERT INTO ?? SET ?",['Party', newParty],function(error, result, fields){
          if(error){
            return connection.rollback(function(){
              throw error;
            });
          }
          else{
            Party_Id = result.insertId;
            var infoObj = {
              // an Object
            }


            connection.query('INSERT INTO ?? SET ?', ['Memo_Info', infoObj], function(error, result, fields){
              if(error){
                return connection.rollback(function(){
                  throw error;
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        Party_Id = idfield.val();
        var infoObj = {
          // an Object
        }

        connection.query('INSERT INTO ?? SET ?', ['Memo_Info', infoObj], function(error, result, fields){
          if(error){
            return connection.rollback(function(){
              throw error;
            });
          }
        });
      }
      connection.commit(function(error) {
        if (error) { 
          return connection.rollback(function() {
            throw error;
          });
        }
        console.log('Transaction Complete.');
        connection.release();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I wrote this piece of code to make a transaction in **node-mysql**, But if,

```
 connection.query('INSERT INTO ?? SET ?', ['Memo_Info', infoObj], function(error, result, fields)
```

This query doesn't run Somehow, Affect of

```
connection.query("INSERT INTO ?? SET ?",['Party', newParty],function(error, result, fields)
```

This one doesn't roll back.

[I've set autocommit = 0]

Comment: What engine are your tables using? Is it InnoDB or some other engine that supports transactions?

Answer (score 3):

**Gotcha #1**

Check which engine your tables are using:

```
show table status;
```

If your table in question is set to `MyISAM`, you've found the problem. MyISAM does not support transactions and thus cannot be rolled back. You can alter the table to use `InnoDB` as the engine to fix the issue:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

or set it when the table is created:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
...
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Gotcha #2**

If you're using a pooled connection, make sure your rollback query is using the same connection.

Calling `pool.query()` isn't guaranteed to use the same connection, though it may seem to during development and testing.

See the docs for [`pool.getConnection()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections) to make it work.